# How to create XPath with following-sibling or preceding-sibling

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have 2 locators:

```
"//td[contains(text(),'{0}')]/following-sibling::td//input[@type='checkbox']"
"//td[contains(text(),'{0}')]/preceding-sibling::td/input"
```

they both very similar. I cannot figure out how to combine them in one so it will work for both cases.

Comment: May be you can show the html

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to find a table row which meet following 3 conditions:

1) contains specify string 
2) includes a check box 
3) includes a input html element

```
//td[contains(text(),'{0}')][../td//input[@type='checkbox'][../td/input]
```

Answer (score 0):

XPATH support OR | and AND & operators.

```
"//td[contains(text(),'{0}')]/following-sibling::td//input[@type='checkbox'] | //td[contains(text(),'{0}')]/preceding-sibling::td/input"
```